# Manage a multi-group application in django using a middleware

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to Django.

Me and my team are working on a Django (vers. 2.1.7 With python 3.5.2) application. The application is currently used by a group of people (I'll call this group A), but the idea is to manage several different groups (B, C, etc.), so that every group will be able to see only the data under their sphere of. In other words, we have to build a multi-platform architecture, with just one server, one domain and one db.

The trivial (but long and boring) way to do so would probably be something like this:

1. Add a "platform" field to every relevant model (and migrate), and set a default value equals to the current existing platform.
2. Change all the "select" queries so to filter the results according to the current user's platform.
3. Change all the "write" queries so to set the correct value in the "platform" column.

A co-worker suggested that it may be possible to define a middleware that would handle the second and third steps, but i'm quite puzzled and not very sure that this could be possible. I'm not a django expert by any mean

I'd like to know if you think it is possible to build such a middleware, and how do you think it should be structured.

If no solution is possible i'll probably be happy enough with the 'standard' solution i mentioned. Maybe step 3 can be achieved by overriding  the models' save() method? If so, i wonder if there's a way to accomplish step 2 in a similar fashion.

Thank you in advance,
have a great day

Comment: how would you determine to what 'platform' a user belongs to? You might want to have a look at this [multi-tenant solution](https://github.com/bernardopires/django-tenant-schemas) if you're using PostgreSQL, but it might be too complicated for what you want.

Comment: Not sure what middleware could achieve in this: you'd be able to add the 'platform' to the request object maybe (or to the session), so you have access to it in all your views. That could be helpful. But you'd still have to ensure in your models that you make the correct queries and save correctly.